# Color Indicator for Code Changes not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My installation of Visual Studio 2010 (Professional) doesn't show me different colors in the margins of recently changed lines, as described in

http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/abhijitjana/archive/2011/03/17/color-indicator-for-code-changes-track-changes-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

even though I have the checkboxes "Track changes" and "Selection margin" checked, as described in the above document.

Anyone else have this problem too? Perhaps some ideas to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Productivity Power Tools Add-on for VS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) as an alternative.  It shows changes in the scroll-bar.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, have installed it as a stopgap solution. But I think the coloring in the margins would be easier to see, since it would be on the left rather than the right hand side.

Comment: Can't wait for VS2012.  MS promises that it will be comprised of managed code.  This means that it will be easy enough to debug.  For now, if it's broken, I simply look for a workaround.  Hope it's close enough for what you're doing. :)